# Whom he saw but little hope of

Tags: questions

"He forgot his enmity to Manfred, whom he saw but little hope of dispossessing by force; "

I'm reading a novel called The castle of Otranto. 
 And I'm confused the usage of 'but' in the sentence above.

Does it have the same meaning without 'but' ,and 'but' can be removed?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Yes, it would have the same meaning if you removed the *but*, though it would change the flavor, or style, of the piece. The *but* here is an example (I believe) of *elision* "he saw ***nought** but a little*..." or "he saw ***nothing** but a little*".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it means the same thing with or without 'but.'

Here, 'but' approximately means 'only.'

Comment: It means 'only'. "We go but rarely, sir." says Caroline Bingley in the script for the 1995 Pride and Prejudice series. Meaning, they only rarely attend court assemblies.

Comment: @anamone It has a different distribution, which I think CactusHouse is implying.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - How does a different distribution apply to this single case?

Comment: @anemone Which single case? A word's 'distribution' refers to all  possible positions it might take in an acceptable sentence. 'He saw but little hope of dispossessing ...' works as a dated expression; 'He saw only little hope of dispossessing ...' doesn't. // Sorry about the typo.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I'm aware that it is dated. That's why I'm quoting the script, which (I suppose) is intended to feel dated as well (I wasn't able to find it in the book though). I'm disputing 'approximately', because I think in this particular sentence it _exactly_ means 'only'.

Comment: I'd say 'he saw but little hope' means 'he saw only a faint hope', not 'he saw only little hope'. Defining words by synonyms implies they're interchangeable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite. Thank you. I hope I never suggested that 'but' can be _replaced_ by 'only' in this sentence. I just think that they do _mean_ the same.

Comment: @anamone It has a different distribution, which I think CactusHouse is implying.